# Is there any process of running application after terminating in iOS?

Tags: ios

I was developing application which trigger some function every time after application is terminate but in iOS I haven't found any solution for this process.

Can anyone suggest me the process to run application after terminate application in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is no such a thing to be followed. Technically speaking, the [`UIApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) seems that it does *not* contains a method that works *after* terminating the application, the only method that relates to termination is [applicationWillTerminate(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate):

> Tells the delegate when the app is about to terminate.

However, clearly, that does not mean it will run after application termination.

As an alternative, you could design your app to be interactive with *[notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)*; Whether they are push or local notifications, they will be triggered even if the application is terminated, your responsibly -as a third party developer- is to tell (schedule) notifications to be received by your application, the system handles the process of how should they fired.